# Finding rate in exponential decay

Tags: functions

Using the exponential decay eqution:  I = Io * e^(-kx)

-k = rate, x = time, Io = initial amount

I was asked to find the rate (-k). We were given the following information, when x = 2 I = 12 and when x = 3 I = 7.9. I know that to find the rate it's generally: ln 2/T or x in this case, but we are given two points x=2 and x=3 with different I's, so i'm unsure how this would work in this case. I did calculate one rate but it only seems to apply to x=3:

7.9 = 12 e ^(-k x 3)

(7.9/12) = e^(-k x 3)

-k x 3 = ln (7.9/12)

k = -1/3 ln (7.9/12)

k = 0.14

and i tested this with x=3 and it worked and i got 7.9 but it doesn't work with x=2 so i'm assuming its not the correct rate in general. So how can I find -k in this example?

Comment: Please explain where does the 12 come from in "7.9 = 12 e ^(-k x 3)". It seems that I(0) was not given as 12.

Comment: yeah that's true. The 12 was just another piece of information we were given which said that at x=3 I = 12. I guess we arent given the Io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**

Let us assume that the model is $$I(x)=I_0~e^{-kx}$$ and now, apply the data you are given. So, $$I(2)=I_0~e^{-2k}=12$$  $$I(3)=I_0~e^{-3k}=7.9$$ If we write the ratio of these two expressions, we have $$\frac{I(2)}{I(3)}=\frac{I_0~e^{-2k}}{I_0~e^{-3k}}=e^k=\frac{12}{7.9}$$ then, taking the logarithm $$k=\log \frac{12}{7.9}=\log(1.51899)=0.418044$$ Now, we can use this value to compute $I_0$ from, for example, $I_0=12e^{2k}$ and obtain $I_0=27.6879$